# Are parameters case sensitive in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I created a test jenkins job pipeline. This job has String parameter - '**testVar**'

**Jenkinsfile code:**

```
println("env.TESTVAR=" + env.TESTVAR)
println("testVar: " + testVar)
println("perform env.testVar = env.testVar + '-changed'")
env.testVar = env.testVar + '-changed'
println("env.testVar=" + env.testVar)
println("params.testVar=" + params.testVar)
println("params.TESTVAR=" + params.TESTVAR)
println("testVar=" + testVar)
```

I started the job with testVar equal to 'testValue'.

**Jenkins output:**

```
[Pipeline] echo
env.TESTVAR=testValue
[Pipeline] echo
testVar: testValue
[Pipeline] echo
perform env.testVar = env.testVar + '-changed'
[Pipeline] echo
env.testVar=testValue-changed
[Pipeline] echo
params.testVar=testValue
[Pipeline] echo
params.TESTVAR=null
[Pipeline] echo
testVar=testValue-changed
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why `env.TESTVAR=testValue`? I have `testValue` parameter, not `TESTVALUE`. Are jenkins parameters (accessed from Groove code as **env**.VARNAME) **case-insensitive**?
2. Why `params.TESTVAR=null`? Are jenkins parameters (accessed from Groove code as **params**.VARNAME) **case-sensitive**?
3. Why `env.testVar=testValue-changed` and `testVar=testValue-changed` after performing `env.testVar = env.testVar + '-changed'`, but `params.testVar=testValue`. Why has the value not changed?

Comment: There seems to be a good bit of confusion here about the difference between environment variables versus parameters and their scope and mutability properties. I am unsure how to convey an explanation, but all of what you are observing is certainly expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open bug for this one](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16255).

Basically, params from parametrized build are copied to env of the node... and environment variables are known to be case-insensitive, which is the bug mentioned above.

Whereas params are just a snapshot of the input paramters, immutable and case sensitive as you have found.